# Obtain required result with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql

I've came up with the following query (with mysql ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode off)

```
SELECT
      sum(case when B.value1 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS totalCount,
      case when B.value1 = 3 AND C.value2 = 28 then A.value3 else 0 end AS infoField
    FROM node as A
      JOIN node_2 as B ON B.entity_id = A.nid AND A.type = 'feed_likes'
      JOIN node_3 as C ON C.nid = A.nid
```

What I need is the number of rows when B.value1 = 3 and the value of A.value3 IF there's a row where B.value1 = 3 AND C.value2 = 28 (otherwise set it to 0).

What it returns is exactly what I want:

In case B.value1 = 3 AND C.value2 = 28

| totalCount | infoField |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 'xyz' |

In case B.value1 = 3 AND C.value2 != 28

| totalCount | infoField |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 |

However, when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode ON I need to add a `Group By` with all fields that I use in the query, which destroys the result I initially wanted.
Any idea how to obtain the required output with `GROUP BY` ?

The errors shown are:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

AND

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db.A...' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Comment: repeat the case expression in the group by clause

Comment: just like this ```GROUP BY case when B.value1 = 3 AND C.value2 = 28 then A.value3 else 0 end``` ?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant